# Knockout 3.2 component data context

Tags: data-binding, knockout.js, datacontext, knockout-components

I am using Knockout 3.2 and the new component system. I am trying to have components that include sub-components.

`Home Page (component - with HomePageViewModel)
  NewsFeed1 (component with HomePageViewModel.NewsFeedViewModel1)
  NewsFeed2 (component with HomePageViewModel.NewsFeedViewModel2)`

**HomePageViewModel**

```
var viewModel = (function () {
    function viewModel() {
        this.message = ko.observable("Welcome to DKT!");
        this.newsFeedViewModel = new gr.viewModel();
        this.newsFeedViewModel2 = new gr.viewModel();
        this.newsFeedViewModel.message("Message 1");
        this.newsFeedViewModel2.message("Message 2");
    }
    return viewModel;
})();
```

**NewsFeedViewModel**

```
var viewModel = (function () {
    function viewModel() {
        this.message = ko.observable("This is the profile!");
    }
    return viewModel;
})();
```

As you can see the `HomePageViewModel` contains both the `NewsFeedViewModel`. I now want to be able to use these as the DataContext/BindingContext of my two components but this does not seem to work.

**Home.html**

```
<news-feed data-bind="newsFeedViewModel"></news-feed>
<news-feed data-bind="newsFeedViewModel2"></news-feed>
```

Both these components do not use the ViewModels from the `HomePageViewModel` but uses a new `NewsFeedViewModel`. How can I make the datacontext of both these components bind to the viewModels stored in the top component (home)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally, you would want to supply your component with any data via `params`. For example, with your structure, you could create the component like:

```
ko.components.register("news-feed", {
    viewModel: function (params) {
       this.vm = params.vm;
    },

    template: "<h2>News Feed</h2><div data-bind=\"text: vm.message\"></div>"
});
```

Then, you would define the elements like:

```
<news-feed params="vm: newsFeedViewModel"></news-feed>

<news-feed params="vm: newsFeedViewModel2"></news-feed>
```

You could choose to pass the `message` in directly for each and/or choose whatever names make sense for your params (rather than `vm`).

Sample: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/fssXE/

Comment: Hi again, would you please have a look to the following code http://jsfiddle.net/fssXE/3/. I have added a function in the viewModel, and bound it to a function in the viewModel. At such point, if I try to access any data from the viewModel it will always be undefined. I have not been able to access the data from functions in the viewModel.

Comment: You've run into a limitation of the `click` binding in Knockout. It always uses the current `$data` object as the `this` value when calling the event handler function. My [Knockout Punches](http://mbest.github.io/knockout.punches/) library modifies `click` (among other things) to work the way you expect: http://jsfiddle.net/fssXE/5/

Comment: otherwise, @user2465083, you can use a `with: vm` within your component's template and then bind directly to the methods/properties on `vm` and it will have the right context.  Here is a sample: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/3vE3S/